# How can I retain the console input in mplayer when reading from stdin?

Tags: shell-script, grep, pipe, console, mplayer

I'm playing around with the **command line interface** of `mplayer`. I'd like to script it in the following way

```
find /some/path/ -type f | grep -vif blacklist | mplayer -shuffle -playlist -
```

where `blacklist` is a text file with artist or song names I'd rather ignore when I have visitors or my son is around (lot's of swear words... :D)

When `mplayer` encounters the `-` character, it disables the console input. From the man page:

```
-noconsolecontrols
          Prevent MPlayer from reading key events from standard input.  
          Useful when reading data from standard input.  This is automatically  
          enabled when - is found on the command line. [snip]
```

This blocks me from seeking in the file and skipping individual songs. Funnily, this works for videos, because the video window still accepts the usual keyboard inputs.

How can I have the regular console input back? I would like to avoid using a temporary file, although this is of course the easiest solution. `-slave` and `-input` don't seem suited and trying `-consolecontroles` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feed the input on a file descriptor other than standard input.

```
find /some/path/ -type f | grep -vif blacklist |
mplayer -shuffle -playlist /dev/fd/3 3<&0 </dev/tty
```

Explanation of the last line: the data from grep is coming in on standard input, which is [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 0. There's no way to pipe to anywhere but standard input in the shell, but we can do a bit of extra plumbing. First, we connect file descriptor 3 to wherever file descriptor 0 is: `3<&0`. Then we connect file descriptor 0 (i.e. standard input) to the terminal: `</dev/tty`. We tell mplayer to read the playlist from file descriptor 3; mplayer expects a file name, so we pass it `/dev/fd/3`, which when opened by a process behaves just like file descriptor 3 in that process at that point.

Note that the order of redirections is important, and counterintuitive if you have the wrong intuition. `3<&0 </dev/tty` has fd 3 read from where fd 0 read before, and fd 0 read from `/dev/tty`. `</dev/tty 3<&0` would have both fd 0 and fd 3 read from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: wow, this works! I don't fully understand what's going on, though.

Comment: Read from right to left; `/dev/tty` is the standard input, `3<&0` redirects the standard input (fd `0`) to *another one* (fd `3`) (you might have seen `2&>0` for **output** redirection) `mplayer` is told to read the playlist from this other one, i.e `/dev/fd/3`, *which is not stdin* and thus doesn't trigger the console input disabling.  (Hope I got it right and you don't mind me chipping in, @Gilles.)

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda overkill, but could still be a viable solution: Use some [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) [filesystem](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems) supporting filtering, e.g. [FilterFS](http://filterfs.sourceforge.net/) or [rofs-filtered](http://ebixio.com/rofs-filtered/). [RevealFS](http://git.freitagsrunde.org/?p=revealfs.git;a=summary) sounds also handy - it is hiding files that lack a `user.public` [extended file attribute (`xattr`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux).

Using one of these, you could probably tell `mplayer` to shuffle all files and thereby keep `stdin` controls.  (Compared to creating two playlists, this is rather much effort, though.)

Comment: thanks for the links, these are interesting pieces of software.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to explicitly diddling with file descriptors, in Bash you have a convenient way to do pipelines-as-FDs:

```
mplayer -shuffle -playlist <(find /some/path -type f -not -name '*.foo')
```

You have both `<(COMMAND)` (pipe output from command) and `>(COMMAND)` (pipe output into command) for this kind of purpose.  They typically work by using /proc/self/fd/ filenames instead of /dev/fd/ ones, but the effect is the same, just without all the legwork.

Bear in mind, of course, that mplayer will look for non-absolute playlist content files in the same directory as the playlist file; in this case, /proc/self/fd.  (The same is true of the /dev/fd solution.)  You also have no way to capture exit codes from the command running in `<()` or `>()`, without feeding them manually through the command’s stdout and picking through that data on the other side—for everyday command-line use, this doesn’t matter, but for scripting it can be quite bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs -o` option, e.g.:

```
find /some/path/ -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | grep -vif blacklist | xargs -0 -o mplayer -shuffle
```

`man xargs`:

> -o, --open-tty
>
> Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an  interactive
>                 application.