# Mplayer controls when using stdin playlists

Tags: shell, pipe, mplayer

I ran across this post: [How can I retain the console input in mplayer when reading from stdin?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/how-can-i-retain-the-console-input-in-mplayer-when-reading-from-stdin)

But the answer there doesn't work for me.

I'm running the following command:

```
ls -l | grep -e mp3 -e wav | awk '{i=index($0,$9); $0=substr($0,i); printf "./"$0"\n"}' | grep " " | mplayer -playlist -
```

and this works fine. (minus controls)

I try this: (as proposed in the above question)

```
ls -l | grep -e mp3 -e wav | awk '{i=index($0,$9); $0=substr($0,i); printf "./"$0"\n"}' | grep " " | mplayer -playlist /dev/fd/3 3<&0 </dev/tty
```

and it gives me this:

```
Playing /dev/fd/./Pink Floyd - Another Brick in the Wall.mp3.
File not found: '/dev/fd/./Pink Floyd - Another Brick in the Wall.mp3'
Failed to open /dev/fd/./Pink Floyd - Another Brick in the Wall.mp3.
```

can someone explain what I am doing wrong (and how to fix it?)

Currently running ubuntu 12.10 using sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that your file paths are relative, and mplayer seems to interpret that as relative to the playlist's location (and not your working directory or whatever). For a zeroth approximation, you can replace "./" with your current directory, but what I'd find easier is to use

```
find "$(pwd)"  -maxdepth 1 -name \*.mp3 -o -name \*.wav | mplayer -playlist /dev/fd/3 3<&0 0</dev/tty
```

(So your `ls`,`grep`,`awk` is replaced by this `find`. Admittedly, I've not double-checked completely if it is entirely equivalent. Removing the -maxdepth would make it recurse into subdirectories, which might be what you want anyway? `man find` is your friend here.)

Comment: Worked great for me. Was not aware of $(pwd) though, so thanks! It's a wonder how you learn something new about linux every day :P

Answer (score 2):

`mplayer` thinks relative paths in the playlist are relative to the directory where the playlist is. Try using absolute paths; change your `awk` script to something like

```
awk -v dir="$(pwd)" '{ ... ; printf dir "/" $0 "\n" }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the awk alternative. I think that using one "find" command would be more efficient than using a ls, grep, and awk combined (plus it gives for recursive searching).